# XML message parsing in the Spring MVC application

Tags: java, xml, parsing, spring-mvc, jaxb

I'm making a Spring mvc application which deals with a big XML. I'm using JAXB to parse and make objects from it. This XML have 40 000 rows with values which looks like that:

```
<row>  0  0  0 HE++  0       36086.8       36116.5             0          0.52          0.86</row>
<row>  0  0  1 O+  0       36086.8       36116.5             0          0.38          0.62</row>
<row>  0  0  2 H+  0       36086.8       36116.5             0             0             0</row>
```

I separated every row by 10 parts, by spaces and made a new ArrayList, but now i have to make a filter in the browser, where i have to choose dynamically a column from these ten parts and then choose between two values. I have to enter min value and max value in two fields and then get the result between the min and max.
For example, i can choose the third column and for min value i enter:0 and for max:2. The result i have to get is 0,1,2. 
Can someone helps me what is the best way to make that happened. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As I understand, the row separator is a different number of spaces? Could you please confirm that?

Comment: I just use "split" function to split every row by ten parts and every of those parts are ten different ArrayLists<String> from which i want to get values dynamically.

Comment: The problem is that there are different types being stored in the row: String, Integer, Double (briefly). If the order doesn't change, you can write a specific parser (method), that will take the number of column and other parameters (like range), then choose the required parser, validate params (if they are applicable to this type of column) and apply filtering, based on them.